# get_agent_identities: ssh_agent_bind_hostkey: communication with agent failed

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I'm trying to pull to a git repo (with SSH remote url) on a remote server. On my home PC I have an SSH agent running:

```
PS user@PC> ssh-add -L
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDIASDE5AAAAIP69b6DHAqQgKVZWNnhbSbhBXG1OH3yePiAHfdyTU+f1 user@PC
```

When I ssh to the server (using `ForwardAgent yes` in the ssh configuration), I still see the same key:

```
PS user@PC> ssh server
user@server> ssh-add -L
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDIASDE5AAAAIP69b6DHAqQgKVZWNnhbSbhBXG1OH3yePiAHfdyTU+f1 user@PC
```

However, connecting to bitbucket doesn't work, even though I have this public key uploaded to my bitbucket profile:

```
user@server> ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.org
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 71: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "bitbucket.org" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup bitbucket.org:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.141.1] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_d2658e6678 d899d51eb8fc
debug1: compat_banner: no match: conker_d2658e6678 d899d51eb8fc
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-s
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: rsa-sha2-512
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug2: get_agent_identities: ssh_agent_bind_hostkey: communication with agent failed
debug1: get_agent_identities: ssh_fetch_identitylist: communication with agent failed
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
```

What is causing the errors in communication with the agent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same problem occurred to me yesterday when I was trying to forward my key to remote server in VSCode. It turned out the default installation is too old and incompatible with the server's protocol.

Here is how I solve it:

1. Open `PowerShell` with elevated privilege.
2. Uninstall the default installation using:

   ```
   Remove-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
   ```
3. (Optional) Restart if you see something like `UninstallPending` instead of `NotPresent`.
4. Check if the default OpenSSH is completely uninstalled:

   ```
   Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object Name -like 'OpenSSH*'
   ```
5. Install latest client only:

   ```
   winget install Microsoft.OpenSSH.Beta --override ADDLOCAL=Client
   ```

   or follow [Install Win32 OpenSSH Using MSI](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH-Using-MSI) if you don't have `winget`.
6. Check installation and verify the version >= `8.9.1.0`:

   ```
   Get-Command ssh-agent
   ```
7. (Optional) Start the `ssh-agent` service if it's not started.

   ```
   Start-Service ssh-agent
   Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
   Get-Service ssh-agent
   ```
8. (Optional) Add following lines to `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/config`:

   ```
   Host server
     ForwardAgent yes
     AddKeysToAgent yes
   ```

Comment: Yup, the OpenSSH version turned out to be the problem (see [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1958)) but I forgot to update this question. I'm accepting this answer since it contains the correct fix to my situation.

Comment: I also found the version mis-match to be an issue when using the Windows SSH-Agent inside of WSL using https://github.com/jstarks/npiperelay